# JQuery Ajax not calling the page but everything else is working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use JQuery to call a page which will delete a record from the database. The page (part_supplierDelete.php) works correctly when I test it manually. The JS & JQuery bellow all work except for the call to the page. When the deletePartSupplier() method is called the confirm dialog pops up and if you click ok the correct div is removed. But the record is not being deleted and it appears that the page is not being called at all. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I have tried with Chrome, FireFox, and IE 8.

```
function deletePartSupplier( part_supplier_id )
{
    var answer = confirm( "This action cannot be undone. Are you sure you want to remove this supplier from the part?" );
    if( answer )
    {
        $.post( "part_supplierDelete.php?part_supplier_id=".concat(part_supplier_id), removeElement( "PSID".concat(part_supplier_id) ) );
    }
}

function removeElement(divNum) {
  var d = document.getElementById('PartSupplierGroup');
  var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);
  d.removeChild(olddiv);
}
```

*

---------- EDIT -----------
The page is showing up in the raw access log that it is being called. But it is not deleting the record like it should. I can follow the link in the access log and then it deletes the row like it should have.

Here is the access log:

```
/v3/part_supplierDelete.php?part_supplier_id=18
    Http Code: 200      Http Version: HTTP/1.1  Size in Bytes: 2
    Referer: /v3/partEdit.php?part_id=5
    Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.237 Safari/534.10
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using jQuery for `removeElement()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your $.post line with this:

```
$.post( "part_supplierDelete.php?part_supplier_id=" + part_supplier_id, function()
{
  removeElement( "PSID" + part_supplier_id );
});
```

Comment: That didnt help any. I checked the raw access logs and it shows up in there that the page is being called but it is not deleting. I then follow the link in the access log and it will then delete.

Answer (score 1):

The string concatenation operator in JavaScript is (stupidly) `+`, which is much easier and readable than calling `concat()`.

Comment: Also, the + and += operators are the fastest when it comes to strign concatenation.

Comment: @Rodolfo Palma Yep, but not as fast as `['a', 'b', 'c'].join()`. However, mostly useless optimisation, bla bla...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried breaking up the $.post and instead of sending the POST as a GET, sending the data to be deleted as the second parameter for $.post?

This doc shows some examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Yes and I still get the same results.